# Bold font on ios device

Tags: iphone, ios

I've made view with `storyboard`, using `UITableView` with subtitle style `cell`. On simulator my cells looks fine - header is `Bold`, and subtitle `greyed` with smaller font size. However on device(iphone4), everything looks like with same font, and no `Bold` title. Is there something that i'm missing?

Comment: why don't you use custom table cells? you would not have any problem of the content then.

Comment: Don't suppose you're using iOS 7? This seems to be a known bug which numerous other developers are finding :(

Comment: Maybe try explicitly setting the fonts? That's what I've had to do to fix the issue I've had with iOS 7, maybe it'll work in iOS 6 as well. On storyboard, you may be able to select the labels in the cell protoype and then change the fonts? Just set them to "custom" and then whatever you want (or what looks the same as default) and try that?

Comment: I just tried this, but didn't work. Still same font styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by compilling and running project on xcode 4 instead of xcode 5 DP. I've tried to create custom cell, but that didnt work aswell

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally using a bolded font for bold characters, I'm no longer using weight for specify if it should display in bold.

What I mean is... if you want your text bold, use the font "Arial-BoldMT" instead of "Arial" that you will bold with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 20)];
label.text = @"Hello";
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];

UILabel* label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 25, 200, 20)];
label1.text = @"Whats Up?";
label1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10.0];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
```